# Unable to get sql to execute reliably with redshift-connector

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I have created a connection using redshift-connector and I'm finding a number of possible issues.  All I'm trying to do is setup a (reliable) function within my library that will create the cursor and execute the passed sql statement with autocommit enabled, we need to support at a minimum `delete from` and `select from`.

Connection setup:

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host=db_host,
    port=5439,
    database=db_name,
    user=db_user,
    password=db_pass
)
```

Note that in my library we use the @property decorator as follows:

```
@property
def conn(self):
    conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    ...
    )
```

Then when I attempt to follow the instructions here https://pypi.org/project/redshift-connector/ to run sql statements I encounter a variety of problems.  In fact, about the only thing that I have seen work is `select`.

For example,

```
cursor = conn.cursor() 
res = cursor.execute("delete from schema.table where col = "val" 
res.close()
```

Results in nothing being deleted.

Then if I do

```
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor() 
res = cursor.execute("delete from schema.table where col = "val" 
res.close()
```

I get 3 locks created in Redshift, ShareRowExclusiveLock granted:True, AccessShareLock granted:True, ShareRowExclusiveLock granted:False and the execute statement hangs until I delete the locks. After deleting the locks, depending whether or not I terminate the right lock the execute statement will either complete successfully or it will error out.

Terminating all the locks results in nothing getting deleted on a follow up execution.

My current theory is that redshift-connector is not creating and removing locks correctly or efficiently.

As a side note, I have found that I am not able to swap in sqlalchemy-redshift, the latest version of awswrangler seems to expect redshift-connector for some unknown reason (not sure why someone thought it would be fun to reinvent the wheel).  Using sqlalchemy postgresql+psycopg2 or redshift+psycopg2 results in an AttributeError related to autocommit. It would also seem that awswrangler doesn't support or work with sqlalchemy's `execution_options(autocommit=True)`.

I'll also add that the pypi page suggests that there's a redshift_connector tag, there's not.

I would appreciate any help here, if someone knows how to get sqlalchemy to work with awswrangler that would be preferred.

Comment: How big is the table and how long did you wait?

Comment: Very small table, in fact created with from a 2x2 dataframe of numbers, `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})`

Comment: I have just tested and found that I can use sqlalchemy as long as I don't require exclusive locks, i.e. as long as I don't require `autocommit=True`, so statements like `delete from` appear to work.  However, this would mean loading two connector libraries and using a different function depending on desired action.

Comment: "COMMIT" is saving the results.  If you close your connection w/o COMMITting the results there will be no changes to the database.  Autocommit is a connection mode that adds a COMMIT after every statement.  This is why you didn't see any changes without it.  You need to explicitly state COMMIT if you are not in autocommit for changes to be saved.

Comment: @BillWeiner I have enabled autocommit with redshift-connector, however, the results are still highly unpredictable.  Are you suggesting that i should add a sqlalchemy.engine.execute('commit;")?

Comment: When you have autocommit on and your statement "hangs" can you see where it is in its execution?  Nothing about the connector should be affecting the locks so I expect something else is happening

Comment: Adding an explicit commit will save the results of the delete as long as it comes before the connection is closed.  Your lack of commit explains why there wasn't any change in the data when you didn't have autocommit = true.  The more puzzling piece is why things hang with the commit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232103/discussion-between-eric-and-bill-weiner).